# Bootstrap 5 Form Validation

Tags: html, forms, bootstrap-5

I'm using Bootstrap 5 forms where I came across this strange behaviour that I gave `was-validated` class to form which displays the red border across the input field but when I enter something in the text box is automatically removed that red border and replaces it with green border. WHERE THIS AUTOMATIC BEHAVIOUR IS COMING FROM GIVEN THAT I'M NOT USING JS.

```
<form class="was-validated">
    Your Name:
    <input type="text" class="form-control" required>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Beware that your form is missing a real label. The code is not in line with Bootstrap’s guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour is coming from the Bootstrap CSS classes that are automatically applied to form controls when they are used in a form.

When the was-validated class is added to a form, Bootstrap will automatically apply the is-valid class to form controls that are filled in correctly, and the is-invalid class to form controls that are not filled in correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but my question is where is the automatic behaviour coming from? I only yes its  very easy to do with JS that is adding event listener to form but how CSS is doing this?

Answer (score 0):

By default, [the browser is doing form validation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation#using_built-in_form_validation), based on the input’s `required` state, the `type` attribute, and other attributes depending on type.

Bootstrap then uses [`:invalid`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:invalid) and other pseudo-classes to assign styles.

As you can read on the [Bootstrap Form Validation docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/forms/validation/#how-it-works)

> Here’s how form validation works with Bootstrap:
>
> HTML form validation is applied via CSS’s two pseudo-classes, `:invalid` and `:valid`. It applies to `<input>`, `<select>`, and `<textarea>` elements.
>
> Bootstrap scopes the `:invalid` and `:valid` styles to parent `.was-validated` class, usually applied to the `<form>`. Otherwise, any required field without a value shows up as invalid on page load. This way, you may choose when to activate them (typically after form submission is attempted).

The section [Browser defaults](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/forms/validation/#browser-defaults) then provides an example on how to rely on the browser’s validation, if you do not want to run Javascript validations.

So you should only assign the `.was-validated` class once the user submits the form, to not greet the user with a bunch of error styles.

For example by binding to [the `invalid` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/invalid_event). In Javascript you only need to decide when to activate Bootstrap’s error styles, no JS is needed to run the actual validation or assign the `:invalid` pseudo-classes.

```js
document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].addEventListener('invalid', () => document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0].classList.add('was-validated'));
```

```css
/* as used in Bootstrap */
.was-validated input:invalid {
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="validationDefault05" class="form-label">Zip</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationDefault05" required pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric">
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: "Bootstrap then uses :invalid and other pseudo-classes to assign styles."

Question Bootstrap uses such classes to check for form states without JS.

Comment: I’m not sure what you’re trying to say. I updated the answer to better explain how the `was-validated` class is intended to be used.